# How do I unroll this matrix into a vector?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, mnist

I'm trying to adapt this code found on chapter 12 of Python Machine Learning by Raschka and Mirjalili, used to classify the handwritten digits in the MNIST dataset, to work on the Fashion-MNIST dataset from Zalando Research. I get an error about the matrix-unrolling of the training set, even though it worked perfectly with the previous MNIST data and Fashion-Mnist should be structured in the same way.

```
def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):

    labels_path = os.path.join(path, '%s-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz' % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path, '%s-images-idx3-ubyte.gz' % kind)

    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
        magic, n = struct.unpack('>II', lbpath.read(8))
        labels = np.fromfile(lbpath, dtype=np.uint8)

    with open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
        magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", imgpath.read(16))
        images = np.fromfile(imgpath, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(labels), 784)
        images = ((images / 255.) - .5) * 2

    return images, labels
```

I expect the 28x28 images to unfold into 784-long arrays into a len(labels)x784 matrix. There must be something I'm missing about the len(labels) thing that previously worked without issues and now gets the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 26421864 into shape (29507,784)
```

Comment: The number of elements that `fromfile` loads does not match the number expected by that reshape.  The number isn't a multiple of either reshape value.